# Twitter implementation. in login of iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios5, authentication, twitter

I am new in twitter implementation, in my application there is one login screen, I want to give an option of twitter login also ,means user can also login from his twitter account.

please give some useful tips, How to do this.

Comment: please give some reference link

Answer (score 0):

You can use TwitterShare files.

**TwitterShare.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <Twitter/Twitter.h>
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>


@interface TwitterShare : UIViewController
{    
    TWTweetComposeViewController *_tweetSheet;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) TWTweetComposeViewController *_tweetSheet;

- (void)buildTweetSheet:(UIView*) viewOnWhichToShow;
-(void)share:(UIImage*)imageToUpload viewOnWhichToShow:(UIView*) viewOnWhichToShow;


@end
```

**TwitterShare.m**

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
#import "TwitterShare.h"
#import "ProgressIndicator.h"


@implementation TwitterShare
@synthesize _tweetSheet;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View methods

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Showing Tweet Sheet

- (void)buildTweetSheet:(UIView*) viewOnWhichToShow
{
    /* make instance of tweet sheet */
    _tweetSheet = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

    /* Specify the completion handler */
    TWTweetComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result)
    {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        NSString *info;
        if(result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone)
        {
            info = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Saved"];
            ProgressIndicator *indicator = [[ProgressIndicator alloc]init];
            [indicator tweetSuccessOrFail:info view:viewOnWhichToShow];
            [indicator release];
            indicator = nil;
        }
        else if(result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled)
        {
            // statements if tweet sheet cancelled.
        }
        [_tweetSheet release];
        _tweetSheet = nil;
    };

    [_tweetSheet setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Share to Twitter

-(void)share:(UIImage*)imageToUpload viewOnWhichToShow:(UIView *)viewOnWhichToShow
{
    [self setView:viewOnWhichToShow];

    [self buildTweetSheet:viewOnWhichToShow];

    /* add Image To _tweetSheet */
    /* Show our tweet sheet */
    [_tweetSheet addImage:imageToUpload];

    [self presentModalViewController:_tweetSheet animated:YES ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not visited (and bookmarked) [Twitter Developers](https://dev.twitter.com/) and its documentation yet :

- Sign in with Twitter : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter
- SSO with iOS >= iOS5 : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios#Single_Sign-On